# The covariance of certain random variable

Tags: nt.number-theory, pr.probability, prime-numbers, st.statistics

We define two random variables $X_n,Y_n $ on the  sample  space $\{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}$  with counting measure. We  denote by $C_n$ the  covariance of theses two random variables: $C_n=Cov(X_n,Y_n)$.
What is the  assymptotic behavior of  $C_n$ at  infinity?

$X_n(K)=  \text{The number of prime  numbers}\qquad  p\qquad  \text{with} \qquad  p\leq k$

$Y_n(K)=  \text{The number of prime  numbers}\qquad  p\qquad  \text{with} \qquad  p > k$

Comment: Let $\pi$ be the prime counting function. Let $\Omega := \{1,\ldots,n\}$. I think that your random variables are $X_n(k) = \pi(k)$ and $Y_n(k) = \pi(n) - \pi(k)$ (your notation is not clear). Then $C_ n = \mathbb{E}(X_nY_n) - \mathbb{E}(X_n) \mathbb{E}(Y_n) = -\mathbb{E}X_n^2 + (\mathbb{E}X_n)^2$. With the prime number theorem this can be approximated.